# processing.getObject() in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

It seems that `processing.getObject()` is no longer available in QGIS.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
#...
layer = processing.getObject(layer)

# -> ...module 'processing' has no attribute 'getObject'
```

Is there a new way to use `get.Object`?

Comment: Method 'processing.getObject()' is still available in QGIS.

Comment: Don't port to qgis 3 yet - the API has not frozen, so you'll be making extra work for yourself when the release is made! If you want to cause work for yourself, the work in progress processing porting guide is at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/4841/files

Answer (score 5):

I have a copy of the QGIS github project locally, it's a few months old but I was able to find where this changed.

It's worth checking [the list of API changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html), which mentions this

> dataobjects.getLayerFromString() was removed. Use QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString() instead.

Using git line annotations I was able to trace this back to a [change made a few months ago](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/377b181c4eb9804af1d557bf7f57001b25842dc1)...

it looks as if a few methods (including **getObject**) were refactored out and replaced with a single **getLayerFromString()** method

```
def getLayerFromString(string, forceLoad=True):
    """Returns an object (layer/table) given a source definition.

    if forceLoad is true, it tries to load it if it is not currently open
    Otherwise, it will return the object only if it is loaded in QGIS.
    """
    ...
```

But [since then it's been moved](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f84d70323408b19125f3a8f6d67ed207efb281fd) to **QgsProcessingUtils**.

So you could try using `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()`

If using QGIS 2.x, you should still be able to use getObject() as before (can check using `print(processing.__dict__['getObject'])`

Answer (score 0):

Method 'processing.getObject()' is still available in QGIS. It can be observed at net image:

[image]

So, the workaround is as follow:

```
>>>import processing
>>>layer =  processing.getObject("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp")
>>>layer
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x9a9c0104>
```

Comment: processing.getObject() is not available in current master, which will be QGIS v3.0 in months.

Comment: i was going to tag this question qgis-3.0 but noticed there isn't a tag for this. Out of interest what plugin were you using there?

Comment: @StevenKay, there is, just tagged it.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I know that. Sorry, but I didn't see number 3 because I focus in that he used in his question a layer reference instead a uri as parameter (possible cause of error).